# Ping getting Request timed out for domain which dns is hosted in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cmd, amazon-route53

I've updated name server in godaddy and hosted dns in Route 53. It is working as expected in browser. But while pinging domain name/ec2 public ip address in cmd i'm getting Request timed out. Is security group of EC2 instance playing any role to ping response?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEmej.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a typical SG will block incoming ping requests.
You need to enable this as shown in the screen shot below.
[image: Add this to Your Security Group]

Would recommend that you keep the source IP's to whatever IPs/CIDR blocks you plan to ping your EC2 hosts form.